# Pass "username" and "password" to external php file from cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How pass username and password from cakephp web application to an external php file?

Comment: From where you want to pass (model or from controller). and where do you want to send on  another application ?

Comment: Actually I want to pass the username and password to wordpress. For 'SSO'. For that I have created an external php page which does the login for wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a form post to that url, which in cakephp, would be a method of a controller.